# how to migrate the installed software in aws micro server to EBS or S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am running a aws micro server, and because I am still a new user, it is free attach a 30GB EBS volume to my server. so according to the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html), I attached a a 30GB volume to my micro aws instance.

But for the testing purpose, I will start/terminate this micro server many times, so everytime I terminate the server, the installed softwares in the instance storage will be lost, when I start a new instance, I will have to install all the needed softwares again which is too time consuming.

so I wonder, is it possible for me to install all the softwares in the attached volume rather than the storage in the instance.

if I can't, how can I migrate the software and data to EBS or S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The t1.micro instance class *does not even have* instance storage.  Many other instance types do, but not micro -- it only has support for EBS -- the attached volume.  That's the only place you could possibly be installing software on a micro.

If you unchecked the box for "delete on termination" when you set up the volume initially, then it will still be there if you terminate the instance.  You can attach it to a new instance and boot it.  If you didn't select that option, you may still be able to select it now, on properties of the EBS volume.

Of course, terminating an instance serves no particularly useful purpose when testing, unless you're testing whether you know how to terminate an instance... stopping and starting an instance destroys the instance on the physical host where it's running and relaunches it on a different host within the availability zone, with the EBS volumes attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ami from the ec2 micro instance you are using, use this ami to launch the new instance next time. The installed softwares in the previous micro instance will be present.

You can also take a snapshot of the instance to keep the instance backup to be used for future. Ebs volume should not be used to install software.